# Which way to order a shared 2D/3D array for parallel reduction over 1 dimension in CUDA/OpenCL?

Tags: caching, cuda, opencl, reduce, gpu-shared-memory

## Overall goal

I have several reductions to make on a bipartite graph, represented by two dense arrays for vertices and a dense array specifying whether an edge is present b/w the two. Say, two arrays are `a0[]` and `a1[]`, and all edges go like `e[i0][i1]` (that is, from elements in `a0` to elements in `a1`).

There are ~100+100 vertices, and ~100*100 edges, so each thread is responsible for one edge.

### Task 1 : max reduction

For each vertex in `a0` I want to find the maximum of all vertices (in `a1`) connected to it, and then the same in reverse: having assigned the result to an array `b0`, for each vertex in `a1`, I want to find the maximum `b0[i0]` of the connected vertices.

To do this, I:

1. load into shared memory

   ```
    #define DC_NUM_FROM_SHARED 16
    #define DC_NUM_TO_SHARED 16
    __global__ void max_reduce_down(
            Value* value1
        , Value* max_value_in_connected
        , int r0_size, int r1_size
        , bool** connected
        )
    {
        int id_from;
        id_from = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        id_to   = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
        bool within_bounds = (id_from < r0_size) && (id_to < r1_size);

        //load into shared memory
        __shared__ Value value[DC_NUM_TO_SHARED][DC_NUM_FROM_SHARED]; //FROM is the inner (consecutive) dimension
        if(within_bounds)
            value[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = connected[id_to][id_from]? value1[id_to] : 0;
        else
            value[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = 0;
        __syncthreads();

        if(!within_bounds)
            return;
   ```
2. reduce

   ```
    for(int stride = DC_NUM_TO_SHARED/2; threadIdx.y < stride; stride >>= 1)
    {
        value[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x] = max(value[threadIdx.y][threadIdx.x], dc[threadIdx.y + stride][threadIdx.x]);
        __syncthreads();
    }
   ```
3. write back

   ```
    max_value_connected[id_from] = value[0][threadIdx.x];
   ```

### Task 2 : best `k`

Similar problem, but reduction is only in for vertices in `a0`, I need to find the `k` best candidates are chosen from connected in `a1` (`k` is ~5).

1. I initialize the shared array with zero elements except for the 1st place

   ```
    int id_from, id_to;
    id_from = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    id_to   = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    __shared Value* values[MAX_CHAMPS * CHAMPS_NUM_FROM_SHARED * CHAMPS_NUM_TO_SHARED]; //champion overlaps
    __shared int* champs[MAX_CHAMPS * CHAMPS_NUM_FROM_SHARED * CHAMPS_NUM_TO_SHARED]; // overlap champions


    bool within_bounds = (id_from < r0_size) && (id_to < r1_size);
    int i = threadIdx.y * CHAMPS_NUM_FROM_SHARED + threadIdx.x;
    if(within_bounds)
    {
        values[i] = connected[id_to][id_from] * values1[id_to];
        champs[i] = connected[id_to][id_from] ? id_to : -1;
    }
    else
    {
        values[i] = 0;
        champs[i] = -1;
    }

    for(int place = 1; place < CHAMP_COUNT; place++)
    {
        i = (place * CHAMPS_NUM_TO_SHARED + threadIdx.y) * CHAMPS_NUM_FROM_SHARED + threadIdx.x;
        values[i] = 0;
        champs[i] = -1;
    }
    if(! within_bounds)
        return;
    __syncthreads();
   ```
2. reduce it

   ```
    for(int stride = CHAMPS_NUM_TO_SHARED/2; threadIdx.y < stride; stride >>= 1)
    {
        merge_2_champs(values, champs, CHAMP_COUNT, id_from, id_to, id_to + stride);
        __syncthreads();
    }
   ```
3. write the results back

   ```
    for(int place = 0; place < LOCAL_DESIRED_ACTIVITY; place++)
        champs0[place][id_from] = champs[place * CHAMPS_NUM_TO_SHARED * CHAMPS_NUM_FROM_SHARED + threadIdx.x];
   ```

## Issues

- How do I order (transpose) the elements in the shared array, such that memory access uses the cache better?
- Does it matter at this point, or is there much more I can gain from other optimizations?
- Would it be better to transpose the edge matrix if I needed to optimize for Task 2? As far as I understood, there is a symmetry in Task 1, so it doesn't matter there.

## P.S.

I have delayed unrolling loops and doing the first reduction iteration while loading, since I thought it is too complicated to do before I have explored simpler ways.

For Task 2, it would be nice to not load zero elements, since the array would never need to grow, and only start shrinking once log(`k`) steps have been made. This would make it `k` times more compact in shared memory! But I dread the resulting index math.

### Syntax and Correctness

The unusual types are just `typedef`'ed `int`s/`char`s/etc. - AFAIK, in GPUs, it makes sense to compactify those as much as possible. I have not run the code yet, no need to check for indexing errors.

Also, I am using CUDA, but I am interested in an OpenCL perspective as well, since I think the best solution should be the same, and I will be using OpenCL in the future anyway.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I figured this out.

The two alternatives that I am considering are to have reductions work on the **y** dimension, and independent on the **x** dimension, or vice versa (**x** dimension being the contiguous one). In any case, the scheduler is able to assemble threads into warps along the **x** dimension, so some coherence is guaranteed. However, having coherence extend beyond a warp would be great. Also, due to the 2D/3D nature of the shared arrays, one would have to limit the dimensions to 16 or even 8.

To ensure coalescence within a warp, the scheduler has to assemble warps along the **x** dimension.

If reducing over **x** dimension, after each iteration, the number of active threads in a warp will halve. However, if reducing over **y** dimension, it is the number of active warps that will halve.

So, I need to reduce over **y**.

Unless the transpose (load) is the slowest, which is an abnormal case.

Answer (score -1):

Coalesced buffer reads really matter; kernels can be 32x slower if you don't do them. It can be worth doing a re-arrangement pass if it means being able to do them (of course, the re-arrangement pass needs to be coalesced as well, but you can often leverage shared local memory to do this).